# Move views from one region to another in caliburn

Tags: caliburn

I need to move views from one content control to another, I have no problems with shutdown the views in one control take the view models to the other presentermanager but how can I set the view to be there also? I don't want the views to be created again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the view instance is cached inside the VM, you should automatically get the previous instance hooked when you open the VM in a different PresenterManager.
You also have to bind each of the two ContentControl to different PresenterManager.CurrentPresenter:

```
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding PresenterManager1.CurrentPresenter}" />
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding PresenterManager2.CurrentPresenter}" />
```

*(sorry for possible errors in property naming, you are probably using old 1.1 version)*

Comment: So I only need to move the vm to another manager and he'll do the rest?

Comment: Yes, if the View part is handled with bindings similar to those I wrote.